# ASP Form Array Data binding

Tags: asp.net, arrays, forms, http-post

I've been busy working on this for the past couple of days trying to figure this out but I haven't found a definite answer as how to handle this.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Activity
    int Id
    string Name
    DateTime Date
    int DurationMinutes
    string Comment

    ICollection<Tags> Tags
    ICollection<Sources> Sources
```

The regular properties will bind like they should. I also want users to be able to add tags and sources to the activity.

Here's the form structure:

[image: form visual]

and here's how I currently save it:
[image: result]

This way, the data will be send as regular strings. I was wondering what would be a nice way to implement this.

I was thinking about creating a custom ModelBinder to return a proper activity as the sources all need to be created first. What would be a proper way to store the data in the front-end to do this? Or is this approach totally wrong?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I've posted this question but now I have completed the form I will post my solution here.

The front-end part was already covered in the question itself and the JSON that get's send with the request looks like this:

```
{"Type":"Book","Details":{"Name":"Book1","Chapter":"1","StartPage":"5","EndPage":"23"}},{"Type":"WebPage","Details":{"Name":"Page1","Url":"sometesturl.com","PageTypeIDs":"1"}}
```

This data will be bound to the ICollection< Source > as seen in the question.

I have had some trouble with the JSON not being in the valid format because the string holds multiple JSON objects but isn't in an array [].

In C# I have created a custom modelbinder to bind all the data like so:

```
public class ActivityTimerModelBinder : IModelBinder { }
```

I get the form data:

```
string sourcesJSON = request.Form.Get("Sources");
```

Then the method itself:

```
private List<Source> CreateSourcesFromJSON(string inputJSON)
    {
        List<Source> sources = new List<Source>();

        string validjson = "[" + inputJSON + "]";

        dynamic[] items = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(validjson);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            string type = item["Type"];

            string serialized = jsSerializer.Serialize(item["Details"]);

            switch (type)
            {
                case "Book":
                    Book b = jsSerializer.Deserialize<Book>(serialized);
                    sources.Add(b);
                    break;
                case "WebPage":
                    WebPage p = jsSerializer.Deserialize<WebPage>(serialized);
                    sources.Add(p);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        return sources;
    }
```

Still, if there are any suggestions about how to improve this deserialization process of the json I'd be honoured.

Note: I have made a dynamicForm jQuery function which generates(optionally) the form based on JSON and outputs the result as JSON to a HTML element.
It's on GitHub here:

github.com/noelheesen/jQuery.dynamicForm